# Javascript is not loading on laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to load some javascripts on laravel but it is not loading, i can't figure out the problem, please someone help me.
here is the code

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#start_date').datepicker({

            })
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Have you added @yield('script') to the parent blade ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `@yield('script')` is defined in the parent blade.

> When defining a child view, use the Blade `@extends` directive to specify which layout the child view should "inherit". Views which extend a Blade layout may inject content into the layout's sections using `@section` directives.
>   (...) the contents of these sections will be displayed in the layout using `@yield`

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-a-layout)

Comment: Thank you very much, i have added it now it is working. Thank you again

Comment: Great. Please mark the answer as correct to close the question.